# JavaScript Json формат как получить свойства

Tags: javascript, json

Есть Json формат такой

```
{
 Skills: [
      {
        Skill: [
          { '$': { Name: 'Night Bird', Cd: '2' } },
          { '$': { Name: 'Moonlight Lasers', Cd: '7' } }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

И как мне получить свойства Name или Cd?

Comment: Это JSON или уже объект?

Comment: Да всё так же, как и в объектах. Skills[0].Skill[0].$.Name

Comment: Для обращения к таким элементам объекта (которые содержат в названии ключа спец. символ), требуется указывать название пропорции в кавычках (пр. `someObject['$'].Name`).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar и вправду, совсем забыл что к `$` можно обращаться без кавычек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете обратиться к свойству `'$'` напрямую:

```
Skills[0].Skill[0].$.Name
```

Вывод:

```
'Night Bird'
```